# Ribbon button Custom action that will work across all lists

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to create a ribbon button that will work with all kinds of lists. I mean, the same custom action should work against lists, document libraries, Announcement lists, etc..

Also. It should work regardless of the content types contained in the list.

What should be the custom action definition for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that setting the RegistrationType to ContentType and RegistrationID to 0x solves this problem. 0x corresponds to Content type "Item", so this will work for all types of lists, even the ones for which content type management is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an easy way to test this, but I believe you'd define your Elements.xml file according the the [Custom Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms465980.aspx) and [Ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458369.aspx) schemas as usual, but omit the `RegistrationId` and `RegistrationType` attributes on the [`CustomAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460194.aspx) element:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction
        Id="[Your.Ribbon.ID.Here]"
        Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.[Your.Location]">
            <!-- Your Ribbon Definitions Here -->
    </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few answers on the SharePoint overflow site

http://www.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6158/how-do-you-create-a-ribbon-button-custom-action-that-will-appear-on-all-kinds-of

Also, i tried CBono's answer a few different ways, but couldn't get it to work. I think if you remove the RegistrationType and RegistrationId, you need to manually show the tab using code

```
SPRibbon ribbon = SPRibbon.GetCurrent(this.Page);
if (!ribbon.IsTabAvailable("Ribbon.CustomTabExample")) {
    ribbon.MakeTabAvailable("Ribbon.CustomTabExample");
}
```

More info at these links

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/390e3409-eba6-4674-9095-c29efcd9bd04

http://msmvps.com/blogs/cobrien/archive/2010/01/25/adding-ribbon-items-into-existing-tabs-groups-ribbon-customization-part-2.aspx